# Simple math facts game

Tags: javascript, game, random, quiz

I've made a simple game for testing math facts (think practice for elementary school-age kids). It displays a random addition, subtraction, multiplication, or division problem, and feedback on if the right answer was entered.

For now it works interacts with the user via `prompt()`, but I plan to add a GUI later. You can exit out of the infinite `prompt()` loop by clicking cancel.

I'd like feedback on how to improve the code, particularly if there's a better way of doing the `getCorrectAns()` function, and if I'm using best practices.

```js
var maxNum = 12,
  stillPlaying = true,
  ans, isCorrect = '',
  correctAns = '',
  sign, num1 = 0,
  num2 = 0,
  prob, correctAns;

function randInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}
function getCorrectAns(n1, sign, n2) {
  switch (sign) {
    case '+':
      return n1 + n2;
    case '\u2212':
      return n1 - n2;
    case '\xD7':
      return n1 * n2;
    case '\xF7':
      return n1 / n2;
    default:
      return false;
  }
}
while (stillPlaying) {
  sign = ['+', '\u2212', '\xD7', '\xF7'][randInt(4)];
  num1 = randInt(maxNum + 1);
  num2 = randInt(maxNum + 1);
  if (sign == '\u2212') num1 += num2;
  if (sign == '\xF7') {
    num2 = randInt(maxNum) + 1;
    num1 *= num2;
  }
  prob = num1 + ' ' + sign + ' ' + num2;
  ans = prompt(isCorrect + prob);
  if (!ans) stillPlaying = false;
  correctAns = getCorrectAns(num1, sign, num2);
  isCorrect = (correctAns == ans) ? 'Correct! ' : 'Incorrect, ' + prob + ' = ' + correctAns + '.\n';
}
```

Comment: `Incorrect, 0 ÷ 0 = NaN.` I think division by zero should be excluded!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From a once over:

- You are using lowerCamelCase, that is good
- Variables like `ans` and `prob` deserve to be written out to `answer` and `problem`
- You are using functions, but I think it can be split up a bit more from a best practices. I would go for something like this:

  ```
  while( stillPlaying ){
    problem = generateNewProblem();
    answer = getAnswer( problem );
    processAnswer( answer );
  }
  ```
- `['+', '\u2212', '\xD7', '\xF7'][randInt(4)];` I wonder why you could not simply use `['+','-','*','/']`. Regardless you should have 4 constants for those values since you use those values repeatedly in other places

  ```
  var plusSign = '+',
    minusSign = '-',
    timesSign = '*,
    divideSign = '/',
    signs = [plusSign , minusSign, timesSign, divideSign];

    if (sign == divideSign) num1 *= num2;
  ```
- This seems funny: `num1 = randInt(maxNum + 1);`, if you were trying to avoid zero, you really need `num1 = randInt(maxNum) + 1;`
- Avoid dropping the curly braces and newlines, even when `if` statements are short like here: `if (sign == '\u2212') num1 += num2;`

Here's my attempt for fun and giggles.

```js
var maxNum = 12,
    signWidt = 12,
    question = document.getElementById( 'question' ),
    input = document.getElementById( 'input' ),
    errorMessage = document.getElementById( 'errorMessage' ),
    greatMessage = document.getElementById( 'greatMessage' ),
    answer;
//Some of these signs are closer to what children use in school
var plusSign = '+',
    minusSign = '\u2212',
    timesSign = '\u2212',
    divideSign = '\xF7',
    signs = [plusSign , minusSign, timesSign, divideSign];


function randInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}

function calculateAnswer(n1, sign, n2) {
  switch (sign) {
    case plusSign:
      return n1 + n2;
    case minusSign:
      return n1 - n2;
    case timesSign:
      return n1 * n2;
    case divideSign:
      return n1 / n2;
    default:
      return false;
  }
}

function displayQuestion( s ){
  //We know the question will never surpass 12 chars..
  var extraneousSpace = 12 - s.length, spaceLeft, spaceRight;
  //Compare last bit to 1, if that bit is 1, the number is odd
  //So we subtract 1 before we evenly divide by 2 and 1 space on the right
  if( extraneousSpace & 1 ){
    extraneousSpace--;
    spaceLeft = extraneousSpace / 2;
    spaceRight = spaceLeft + 1;
  } else {
    spaceLeft = spaceRight = extraneousSpace / 2;
  }
  //Mildly evil re-use of variable and magical space repeating routine
  //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202605/repeat-string-javascript
  spaceLeft = new Array( spaceLeft + 1 ).join( ' ' );
  spaceRight = new Array( spaceRight + 1 ).join( ' ' );
  question.innerText = spaceLeft + s + spaceRight;
}

function generateQuestion(){
  var sign = signs[randInt(4)],
      num1 = randInt(maxNum + 1),
      num2 = randInt(maxNum + 1);  
  
  if (sign == minusSign){
    num1 += num2;
  }
  if (sign == divideSign) {
    num2 = randInt(maxNum) + 1;
    num1 *= num2;
  }  
  answer = calculateAnswer( num1 , sign, num2 );
  displayQuestion( num1 + ' ' + sign + ' ' + num2 )
}

generateQuestion();
input.focus();

input.addEventListener( 'keypress' , function(e){
  console.log( this );
  if( e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13 ){
    if( input.value != answer ){
      errorMessage.innerText = 'Wrong, ' + question.innerText.trim() + ' = ' + answer;
      greatMessage.innerText = '';
    }else {
      errorMessage.innerText = '';
      greatMessage.innerText = 'That is right, here\'s another question';    
    }
    input.value = '';
    generateQuestion();
  }
});
```

```css
#errorMessage { color: red }
#greatMessage { color: green }
```

```html
<pre>
|￣￣￣￣￣￣ |
|   What is  |
|<span id='question'>            </span>| 
|      ?     |
| ＿＿＿＿＿__| 
(\__/) || 
(•ㅅ•) || 
/ 　 づ
</pre>
<input type='text' id='input'><br>
<pre>
<span id='errorMessage'></span><span id='greatMessage'></span>
</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! A few clarifications: I used the actual signs because children will probably be unfamiliar with `*` and `/` as multiplication and division signs. Also, I am only trying to avoid zero as a denominator of a division problem; I have added a quick fix for that.